# How does extending an existing parquet with columns affect impala/spark performance?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, impala

I have an existing setup of parquet files that are being queried from impala and from spark.

I intend to add some 30 relatively 'heavy' columns to the parquet. 
Each column would store an array of structs. Each struct can have from 5 to 20 fields. An array may have a couple of thousands of structs.

Theoretically, parquet being a columnar storage- extending it with columns should not affect performance of *existing* queries (since they are not touching these columns).

- Is this premise correct?
- What should I watch out for doing this move?
- In general, what are the considerations when deciding on the "width"
  (i.e amount of columns) of a parquet file?

Comment: Parquet being columnar storage your filters on columns will be not heavy as it does not need to reference other columns. 
Things to watch out for are the queries to access the elements of the complex data types is a bit messed up in impala.